# Unable to access instantiated data member in python

Tags: python

I'm having problem accessing the data member in python. Not sure why.
These are my files:

```
# main.py
from myprocess import DataProcess as dp

myprocess = dp('apple')
myprocess.process_files()
```

Now for the file where i have a class

```
#myprocess.py
class DataProcess:
def __init__(self, file1):
    self.file1=file1


@classmethod
def process_files():
    print(self.file1)
```

In the process_files method, I have an error :

```
Class 'DataProcess' has no 'file1' member
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use self parameter inside a classmethod. The idea of class method is that the method belongs to the class itself, and not to an instance of the class. Hence if you delete the @classmethod decorator, your code should work

Comment: Also needs to add `(self)` as a parameter.